# Facebook handle expired access tokens

Tags: c#, facebook

Has anybody done the equivalent of [this](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/) PHP solution for dealing with expired access tokens in Facebook in C#?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using the Facebook Javascript SDK and use the FB.getLoginStatus to redirect the user to the right functionality.  I've found that moving things out of C# code into clientside Javascript has really sped up my user experience.  It's amazing what you can get done in it.